# How to parallelize dpkg for large dkms packages?

Tags: apt, dpkg, compiling, dkms

A lot of dkms modules which are installed as apt packages (e.g. `zfs-dkms` and `openafs-modules-dkms`) need a lot of time to build (> 5 minutes) and don't use any parallelization (at least not recognizable in the CPU monitor) for most parts of their processing. `MAKEFLAGS` gets pick up (100 % usage of all CPU cores like during other builds with `make -j16`) for the last part of the process (e.g. for `zfs-dkms` for the last 10 % of the time). Is there any way to use parallelization for the whole run? The output during the slow part of the build is `building initial module for <kernel version>`.

Running Ubuntu 14.04 amd64 with `dpkg` 1.17.13ubuntu1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The environment variable `CONCURRENCY_LEVEL` (e.g. `CONCURRENCY_LEVEL='16'`) is recognized. A lot of modules (e.g. `zfs`) take > 70 % of the time to configure and/or to clean previous builds so that the parallelization with `CONCURRENCY_LEVEL` appears minimal. `configure` can't be sped up in general.